# fsPromises.writeFile callback not being called in Node v12.13.0

Tags: node.js, promise, filesystems, fs

For whatever reason the callback for `fs.promises` is not being called, yet the documentation makes no mention of it only being called if there's an error, which is what I'm assuming would happen...

```
fsp.writeFile('test.txt', 'callback doesnt work', 'utf8', (error) => {
  console.log('callback is never called')
  if (error) console.error(error)
})
```

This is happening (or not happening lol) on version 12.13.0 of Node.

Does anybody know what the deal with this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fs.promises` version of async calls return promises.  They don't accept callbacks.  Use the regular `fs` version if you want to use a callback.

You can see [right here in the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options) that there is no option to pass a callback for the fsPromises versions of the API.

You should be doing it like this:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

fsp.writeFile('test.txt', 'promise works', 'utf8').then(() => {
    console.log("write successful");
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Or, inside an `async` function, you could use `try/catch` and `await` instead of `.then()` and `.catch()`.

Comment: oh yeah makes sense, but then why does the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) say theres a callback?? lol

Comment: oh yeah sorry im trippin out. node is new to me if you couldnt already tell lol

Comment: @PrimitiveNom - You're looking at the `fs.writeFile()` portion of the doc, not the `fs.promises.writeFile()` [portion of the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options).

Comment: yeah i noticed that after looking at the link in your edit. anyways, so would the following syntax suffice for handling the promise? `fsp.writeFile('test.txt', 'testing', error => error)` or should i be handling the promise in a different way? promises are new to me too :/

Comment: @PrimitiveNom - I'd suggest some reading and studying about promises.  See what I added to the end of my answer for the proper syntax for the promises version of that API.

Comment: i have read quite a bit about promises, and i understand the basic stuff like `new Promise(res, rej => { if (cond) {resolveFn(dataPassedForward)} else {rejectFn(dataPassedForward)}).then(data => {do whatever}).catch(data=>{throw data})` but when using them with `fs.promises` its super confusing for me. i always end up in callback hell when everything is working as expected lol. do u know any good reading materials regarding escaping callback hell with `fs.promises`?

Comment: like super nested `fs.promises`

Comment: @PrimitiveNom - Well, you should chain rater than nest.  Promise logic does not usually need to get deeply nested.  Or, you can use `await` which allows you to write very flat-looking code.  I can't really turn this answer into a promises tutorial.  I don't have any particular reading references to recommend.  If you read every question/answer here going forward that is tagged `Promise` (or even read the last few months), you'd be surprised what you learn from seeing all those promise-based problems get solved.

Comment: The `fsPromises` APIs just return a promise that you then use `.then()` and `.catch()` directly on their return value.  Just like in the example I show in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201481/discussion-between-primitivenom-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @PrimitiveNom - Some other answers to read: [How to handle nested promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695770/is-there-a-better-way-to-handle-nested-promises-in-nodejs/48696006#48696006), [How to chain and share prior results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863).

Comment: ty sir. i think i just realized how to do it. i can simply return the value that i need from each `then` function to use in the next `then` function :)

Comment: @PrimitiveNom - Yes, you can return a value or another promise.  That's how you "chain" with promises.

Comment: it was tricky to figure out because i had to store some of the values in a higher scope to preserve them. thats y it was hard for me to understand how to chain them

Comment: @PrimitiveNom - Did you see this [How to chain and share prior results with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863)?  Note how much simpler it is with `async/await`.

Comment: i did see it, but i never read the inline comments, so i didnt think i would be able to use it in my situation. i guess i can and now i will :D im gonna do some more reading on `async/await` right now before i implement that tho. thanks again for all ur help. really appreciate it

Comment: actually im no longer sure anymore that `async/await` is the right approach for what im trying to do. it may just be ignorant and have to read more to get a better understanding of how to accomplish what it is i want to do

Comment: @PrimitiveNom - Since all you've shown so far is a single fs asynchronous call, there's not much we do to help.  If you want further help, I'd suggest you post a new question and include the code for a much larger context for what you're trying to do and folks will have a better chance to advise what your options are both with and without `async/await`.

Comment: im just about to head off for the night, but i will do that tomo if need be. one quick question, is `const r = await () => somePromiseOrValue()` not valid syntax? it throws the error `Malformed arrow function parameter list`. anyways gnite

Comment: @PrimitiveNom -  You `await` a value (that should be a promise), you don't await a function.  You can await the result of a function call as in `const r = await someFunc()`.  And, apparently you're not even correctly defining the arrow function.  That looks wrong to me, but you don't show even a whole statement of code to really see the intent.

Comment: you mind taking a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58619990/7543162)