# Check permission before stat method to avoid errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, traversal, tree-traversal

My first time ever trying to traverse directories, but `stat` is throwing errors for some of the directories due to what seems to be a lack of permission.

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'K:\System Volume Information'`

I'd like to simply avoid calling `stat` on a given directory in the first place if it is going to throw an error, yet I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried looking into ignoring protected directories altogether. However, all of the questions I came across used regular expressions that – to my limited knowledge of MacOS, Linux, and how things are handled under the hood on Windows – didn't seem to be applicable to the Windows environment.

I've tried checking the read and write permissions of the directory before making any call to `stat`, but this doesn't seem to do anything?

```
async function scanDirs(){
  const
    r = await fsp.readFile('./config.json', 'utf8'),
    archives = JSON.parse(r).archives,
    fs = require('fs'),
    { join } = require('path'),
    traverse = async (dir) => {
      try {
        const perm = await fsp.access(dir, fs.constants.R_OK)
        if (perm === undefined){
          const stats = await fsp.stat(dir)
          if (stats.isDirectory()){
            const subfolders = await fsp.readdir(dir)
            subfolders.forEach(path => {
              const fullPath = join(dir, path)
              traverse( fullPath )
            })
          }
        }
      }
      catch (error){
        console.error(error)
      }
    }

  for (const dir of archives){
    traverse(dir)
  }
}
```

I've also just tried checking the permissions of a given folder's children before feeding them back into `traverse`, but this doesn't work either.

```
            for (const path of subfolders){
              const
                fullPath = join(dir, path),
                perm = await fsp.access(fullPath, fs.constants.R_OK)
              if (perm === undefined) traverse(fullPath)
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It can often be subject to race conditions to try to check things before doing an asynchronous operation (this is why `fs.exists()` is deprecated, for example).  Usually, it's better to just attempt the operation and properly  handle any errors you get.  Is there a reason you're afraid to just attempt the operation and properly handle errors?  Plus, you can't pre-test all possible errors anyway so you have to handle errors on the major operation anyway.

Comment: Handling errors then just becomes a task to decide which errors should be skipped and continue other processing and which errors are fatal and the operation should be aborted.

Comment: @jfriend00 i dont believe the code introduces any race situations since `await` is being used? the one error id like to avoid altogether is merely the permissions error. theres two ways to go about it: (1) check the permissions before doing anything else, which doesnt seem to be working for some reason; or (2) somehow acknowledge to avoid querying hidden drives and files which im not even sure can be done. i know `exists` is deprecated, but the documentation suggests using `access` and `stat` which is what im doing?

Comment: @jfriend00 i mean i could just ignore the caught errors, but if i can just avoid code that throws those errors in the first place, so that they dont distract my attention from other possible errors, that would be ideal

Comment: @PrimitiveNom The race condition exists because other programs might change the permissions while your application is traversing the directory. It might happen that the permissions change between the `access` call and the `stat` call.

Comment: @Bergi ahhh right right damn. nonetheless, i dont think the permissions of system files/folders will be changing that regularly

Comment: Of course you can decide to not care about errors that crash your program because they are too rare, but in this case I can't see a reason not to use the proper solution that is both simpler and more robust.

Comment: @Bergi which is?

Comment: @PrimitiveNom Which is handling errors as jfriend suggested

Comment: @Bergi the errors will be handled nonetheless, but id rather not call `stat` or some other method that is going to throw an error due to a lack of permissions if i can simply check permissions before calling the method that throws the error due to a lack of permission